# How to get label text instead of the value of the antd slider

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using the [AntD Slider component](https://ant.design/components/slider/) in my React App and I want to get the value of the label I assigned it instead the normal percentage value when I move the slider.

As you can see in [this Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/slider-text-value-hd8u1?file=/index.js), the `console.log` command prints the percentage value of the slider.

How can I get the 100º, 150º or 200º value of the label, in this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example from Sandbox I just added this:

```
function onAfterChange(value) {
  ...
  console.log(marks[value]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onAfterChange(value) {
  console.log("Valor: ", marks[value]);
}
```

Working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/slider-text-value-forked-xwf12